# .NET MVC use proxy for web service

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller, proxy

I'm using an API called ButterCMS.  I have it set up and working.  It's simple and directly from their documentation:

In package manager console, I run `Install-Package ButterCMS`

I noticed this makes an entry into **References**

[image]

---

The controller code is simple:

```
var apiToken = "mysecretkey";
var client = new ButterCMS.ButterCMSClient(apiToken);
var posts = client.ListPosts(1, 10);

ViewBag.Posts = posts;    //This correctly retrieves my blog posts
```

This is completely working.   Now I want to use a proxy to call this API.
 How can I do this in .NET MVC?

**Edit**:  I already have a proxy setup with an address.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is quite easy since there's already an existing proxy.  You can set a default proxy in your `web.config`, all requests will then use the proxy.

This code works:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy proxyaddress="[Address/PortNumber]" bypassonlocal="false"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```